# send body with "GET" method in axios

Tags: node.js, rest, axios

Is there anyway to send body with `GET` method in axios? because in `postman` it is possible. My backend code as below:

**I'm using `express.js` + `sequelize`**

```
const c_p_get_all = async (req, res) => {
const { category } = req.body;
const sql = `select p.id, p.p_image, p.p_name, p.p_desc, p.p_prize, p.p_size, c.c_name, cl.cl_name
  from products as p
  inner join collections as cl on cl.id = p.p_collection_id 
  inner join categories as c on c.id = cl.cl_category_id
  where c.c_name = ?
  order by p."createdAt" desc;`;
 
try {
  const getData = await Product.sequelize.query(sql, {
    replacements: [category],
  });
   if (getData[0] != "") {
     res.status(200).send({
      s: 1,
      message: "success retrive all products",
      data: getData[0],
     });
   } else {
     res.status(404).send({
      s: 0,
      message: "data not found",
  });
  }
 } catch (err) {
   res.status(500).send({
     message: err,
  });
 }
};
```

**My Frontend with `react.js` + `axios`**

```
const test = "woman";
axios({
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product",
  data: { category: test },
})
  .then((value) => console.log(value))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.response));
```

It always goes to `status 404`, but in `postman` its working, I've tried to search this problem, but no clue. So is there anyway to do it in axios, or should I change my backend to `POST` method or change `req.body` to `req.query`?

Comment: Even if it's possible to add a body to a GET request, it's non-standard and generally a bad idea. In my humble opinion it's MUCH better to change your backend to POST, or just send data in query parameters instead (like http://localhost:3001/api/v1/product?category=test`)

Comment: @ippi yeah I think I will go with your suggestion by using query parameters, because I found that from the axios docs it doesn't allow to send body with GET method. Thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to query parameters and it worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Which query param you have changed exactly ?

Comment: I changed it from `req.body` to `req.query` example `localhost:3001/api/v1/product?category=test`